# Can't access/change to specific directories

Tags: python, excel, directory

I am trying to bring in several sheets from a workbook.  below is the code I am using:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
fileLoc = 'r'+'\\Documents\MOC uploads\WCM weekly-monthly.xlsx' 
rawData = pd.read_excel ( fileLoc, sheet_name ='RawData' )  
product = pd.read_excel ( fileLoc , sheet_name => 'Product' )  
IssueCoils = pd.read_excel ( fileLoc , sheet_name => 'Coils with Issues' ) 
dispCodes = pd.read_excel ( fileLoc ,> sheet_name = 'DispositionCodes' )
```

I get the following error:

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'r\\\Documents\\\MOC uploads\\\WCM weekly-monthly.xlsx'`

I get the same error if I hardcode the filename into each `read_excel` statement.  I thought the `'r'` was supposed to prevent the "\" from being doubled.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `r'\\Documents\MOC uploads\WCM> weekly-monthly.xlsx'`?

Comment: forgot to include the : import pandas as pd statement

Comment: 'r\\Documents\\MOC uploads\\WCM weekly-monthly.xlsx'

Comment: the error is:  [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'r\\Documents\\MOC uploads\\WCM weekly-monthly.xlsx'

Comment: `r` is a decorator for a raw string that doesn't use backslash escapes. Its placed directly before the opening quote as shown in other comments.

Comment: the ">" is a typo  it should be ....WCM weekly-monthly.xlsx

Comment: when using the rawData = pd.read_excel ( r'\\Documents\MOC uploads\WCM> weekly-monthly.xlsx', sheet_name ='RawData' ) i get the same error

Comment: The stackflow editor "corrects" the error message to remove one of each of the doubled backslashes.  I edited to add a third backslash so that it shows message as it shows in my output.  I have tried the code in both Spyder and Jupyter

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
os.chdir(r'\....')
df=pd.read_excel() or pd.read_csv()
```

I still don't understand why the extra step is necessary.